# How to handle pressing any keys in the user control in visual studio vspackage

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

I added usercontrol (textbox) in code editor control. But textbox not handle any keys (arrow, backspace). Keys handle code editor only.
Example:

get IWpfTextView

```
var textManager = (IVsTextManager)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsTextManager));
IVsTextView textView;
textManager.GetActiveView(1, null, out textView);            
var userData = (IVsUserData)textView;
if (userData == null)
    return null;
Guid guidWpfViewHost = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.DefGuidList.guidIWpfTextViewHost;     
object host;
userData.GetData(ref guidWpfViewHost, out host);
return ((IWpfTextViewHost)host).TextView;
```

Add control with textbox

```
Canvas.SetLeft(_control, _view.ViewportRight - 255);
Canvas.SetTop(_control, _view.ViewportTop + 10);
(((System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl)_view).Content as Canvas).Children.Add(_control);
```

But there was a problem when processing keys, their intercepts (the main window as the editor),
keys are not processed. For example arrows, HOME and other.
If so add a textbox, then the letters are printed there. But the other key is handled by the editor, rather than this text box even backspace.
Who knows how to catch and handle correctly?