# Input keyboard not handled in Addin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, vsix, vspackage

Hi I have a problem with vspackage. My Addin is a simple window in which there is  a form in which I write some data in text box. 
If I try to cancel what I wrote ( pressing "BACK" button), it does not work.

How Can I solve this problem?

It seems the same problem : [How to handle pressing any keys in the user control in visual studio vspackage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132095/how-to-handle-pressing-any-keys-in-the-user-control-in-visual-studio-vspackage)

this is the constructor of my command:

```
  private EditMVPCommand(Package package)
    {

        if (package == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("package");
        }

        this.package = package;

        OleMenuCommandService commandService = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
        if (commandService != null)
        {
            var menuCommandID = new CommandID(CommandSet, CommandId);
            OleMenuCommand menuItem = new OleMenuCommand(this.MenuItemCallback, menuCommandID);
            menuItem.BeforeQueryStatus += new EventHandler(OnBeforeQueryStatus);
            commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
        }
    }
```

and this is MenuItemCallBack in which I call the view of my addin :

```
private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       MyView.Show();

    }
```

In the textbox of my view all characters work except BACK, ENTER and TAB

Comment: Is it possibile that nobody have the same problem?

Comment: Is it possible to enter more details? Like placing some code?

Comment: I edited my code @RenatoAfonso